# Finding the Taylor series for $\frac{1}{1-x^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, taylor-expansion

Where I'm stuck

$f(x)=\frac{1}{1-x^2}=\frac{1}{1-x}\cdot\!\frac{1}{1+x}=(1-x)^{-1} \cdot(1+x)^{-1}$

$(1+x)^{-1}= 1-x+x^2-x^3+...+(-1)^{2n}x^{2n}+o(x^{2n})$

$(1-x)^{-1}= 1+x+x^2+x^3+...+x^{2n}+o(x^{2n})$

At this point I have no idea how to multiply all this together.Could you please help?

The answer is $1+x^2+...+x^{2n}$.

Comment: Apparently you know the geometric series for $1/(1-x)$. Now simply replace $x$ by $x^2$ ...

Comment: Please check the answer. The linear term should not be there.

Comment: You can convince yourself that Martin's trick is correct if you compare your $f(x)$ with $\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{1+x}+\frac{1}{1-x}\right)$.

Comment: @user oops, you're right, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For every $x\in(-1,1), \frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}x^i$. So we replace $x$ with $x^2$, and since $x\in(-1,1)\rightarrow x^2\in(-1,1)$ we get $\frac{1}{1-x^2}=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}x^{2i}$.

Comment: Oh, I didn't think I could just replace $x$ by $x^2$. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

In the interest of proving $\sum_{n\ge0}x^{2n}$ is the Taylor series of $\frac{1}{1-x^2}$ expanded at $x=0$, which isn't quite the same point as the limit being correct, use $\frac{1}{1-x^2}=\frac12\left(\frac{1}{1-x}+\frac{1}{1+x}\right)$ to average their Taylor series, giving$$\sum_{n\ge0}\frac12(1+(-1)^n)x^n=\sum_{n\ge0}x^{2n}$$(by separately considering powers of each parity).

Answer (score 1):

It's the geometric progression with  $x $ replaced by  $x^2$:  $\dfrac1 {1-x}=\sum_{n\ge0}x^n\implies \dfrac1 {1-x^2}=\sum_{n\ge0}x^{2n} $.